# AngularJS : Calling a function in a directive from a controller with isolated scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive which is essentially just a search box  with multiple parameters.  In the controller, the search function requires access to a function called `getOptions()` which is used to get the search box settings.  Currently, I have this working by using the default of `scope: false` and using `$scope.getOptions() = function()....` in the directive.

Here is an example code snippet (I don't have the code in front me of so I'm going by memory, this might not be syntactically correct but it does work)

```
angular.module('example', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  function search() {
    //do something using $scope.getOptions()
  }
  // other functions that modify $scope.someParameter1 ....
  }])
  .directive('searchBox', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'someurl.html'
      link: link
    };

    function link($scope) {
      $scope.someParameter1 = something;  // the default
      $scope.someParameter2 = something;  // the default
      $scope.getOptions() = function () {
        //do something with parameters
      }
    }
  });
```

However, this is bad practice and it doesn't work if I have multiple search boxes on the same page, so I am trying to use an isolated scope using `scope: {}`.  I can keep the parameters in the controller and pass them into the `getOptions()` function instead of relying on the `$scope` attributes, but I don't know how I can call `getOptions()` from the controller.  I can't move `getOptions()` from the controller because it calls several functions within the directive.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You *can't directly call method from isolated scope but we can reverse our processes.
We are going to watch changes in additional attributes passed to directive.

### Proof of concept of directive

```
.directive('box', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            outsideScope: '=box'
        },
        template: 'directive box <br> isolated method: {{ wasCalled }}',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('outsideScope', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if(newValue !== oldValue) {
                    try {
                        scope[newValue](); // I'm going to call method with the name as passed string from controller
                    } catch(e) {
                        console.error(e);
                    }     
                }
            });
            scope.wasCalled = 'wasnt called';
            scope.isolateMethod = function() {
                scope.wasCalled = 'was called';
            }
        }
    }
});
```

### Part of controller

```
controller('foo', function foo($scope) {
    $scope.changeOutsideScope = function() {
        $scope.outsideScope = 'isolateMethod';
    }
});
```

### HTML

```
<div ng-controller="foo">
    <button ng-click="changeOutsideScope()">Call</button>
    <div class="directive" box="outsideScope"></div>
</div>
```

*You can in tests as Angular provides `.isolateScope()` method that you can call on compiled element to retrieve scope of directive.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/krzysztof_safjanowski/P8ajy/